# Switch JS function to validate last url string "?xxxx='wyz'"

Tags: javascript, url, switch-statement

I need help with my "switch" code I want to validate the final string of a url to change a background by assigning a class and applying the corresponding CSS, it always returns the "default" case and does not apply to other cases with any URL.

```
var url_location = window.location.href;

switch (url_location) {
    case window.location.href.indexOf('?osf_portfolio_type=Bodega'):
        jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-bodega');
        break;
    case window.location.href.indexOf('?osf_portfolio_type=Terreno'):
        jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-terreno');
        break;
    case window.location.href.indexOf('?osf_portfolio_type=Oficina'):
        jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-oficina');
        break;
    case window.location.href.indexOf('?osf_portfolio_type=Local+comercial'):
        jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-local-comercial');
        break;
    default:
        jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedades-site');
        break;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That is not how switch case works. You can switch between different values, not complex logical statements. You can only do this using regular `if`s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: Separately, what would it even mean to compare the `href` of the location with the result of `indexOf`?

Comment: Oh! thank you very much for the answers now I understand, not everything that is done with an if will always apply to the switch statement.

Comment: Basically only `if (something == value1) { } else if (something == value2) { } else if (something == value3) { }` is easily translateable into a switch case.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("?osf_portfolio_type=Bodega") > -1) {
  jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-bodega');
} 
else if (window.location.href.indexOf("?osf_portfolio_type=Terreno") > -1) {
   jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-terreno');
  }
else if (window.location.href.indexOf("?osf_portfolio_type=Oficina") > -1) {
   jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-oficina');
  }

else if (window.location.href.indexOf("?osf_portfolio_type=Local+comercial") > -1) {
jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedad-local-comercial');
 }
 else{
jQuery('.page-title-bar').addClass('propiedades-site');
}
```

Comment: this technichally answers the question but the code is still an absolute mess, extracting the get parameter value for `osf_portfolio_type` and then doing a switch case around that instead of using `indexOf` repeatedly. This code e.g. breaks if the `osf_portfolio_type` becomes the second get parameter instead of the first one.